# Autogenerated unique field in Doctrine2 entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, uniqueidentifier

I have a Doctrine2 entity with two fields, name and URL. I want to generate the URL field automatically according to name field.

E.g. name "John Doe" will have generated URL "john-doe"

I have implemented the generation of URL field in name setter:

```
public function setName($name) {
  $this->name = $name;
  $this->url = UrlGenerator::generate($name);      
}
```

I want the URL field to be unique but not the name field. The problem is what to do, when two names converts to same URL.

E.g. name "John Doe" => URL "john-doe", "john doe" => URL "john-doe"

I want to add number (for example the entity DB generated id) to the end of URL field in case when the URL already exists in DB, but I have no idea how to implement this in the entity. At first, I can't use entity manager in entity class to check the collision. The second problem is, that I don't know the next generated id before the entity is persisted to DB and it can't be persisted if it URL collides with existing item.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If the number value is irrelevant (just asking), would it be acceptable to use the output of time() ? like "john-doe-" . time(). It will only repeat if 2 entities with the same name are created in exactly the same second (which should be odd in the vast majority of scenarios)

Comment: Well the number shouldn't be too big, since I want to use it as SEF URL.